# HOW to use a column Dataframe Python to find a value in another column of the same Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Borrower=[1,1,1,2,2]
Property_type=[Residential, Other, Other, Land, Hotel]
OMV = [100, 50, 30, 102,45]
```

I have calculated the max OMV per Borrower&Property_Type

```
OMV_max= [100,100,100,102,102]
```

Now I would obtain

```
Property_Type_Borrower = [Residential, Residential, Residential, Land, Land]
```

i.e. I want ti find OMV_max in OMV and return Property_Type

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: mention exactly what you need to compute

Comment: can you post your data as text as opposed to an image? IIUC you need `.map` or `.merge`

Comment: I have changed the question ---> could you help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a dictionary `OMV_to_Property = OMV_to_Property = {100: 'Residential', 50: 'Other', 30: 'Other', 102: 'Land', 45: 'Hotel'}`. Then you can just use a list comprehension like `Property_Type_Borrower = [OMV_to_Property[x] for x in OMV_max]`.